# How does Tenacity work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Previously, only the Mercury's Treads reduced the effect of any kind of CC (by 1 second if my memory is ok).

Now we have 3 items that allow you to reduce any kind of CC: Mercury's Treads, Moonflair Spellblade and Cloak and Dagger. All of these items gives you +35 Tenacity.

How does Tenacity work? Is it a kind of percent reduction based on the duration of the CC or it is a specific amount of static time for all the CCs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Tenacity is a mechanic that reduces the duration of crowd control
>   effects. **It does not affect the potency/strength of the effect.**
>
> Tenacity works on: Blind, Forced Actions (Charm, Fear and Taunt), Pacify, Silence, [Snare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58174/how-does-tenacity-work/58180#comment91992_58180), Slow and Stun.
>
> Tenacity does not work on: Airborne (Knockback, Knockup and Pull) and Suppression.

Contrary to Deotronic's answer, Tenacity does **not** reduce the amount of slow. It only reduces the duration of the any of the CC that is affected by Tenacity. The reduction is reduced by a percentage equal to the Tenacity value. So a champion with 35 Tenacity will have all affected CC reduced by 35% duration.

EDITED to reflect changes to Season 3 tenacity items:

Please note that Tenacity does not stack. There are currently 3 items which provide Tenacity, and they all give 35 Tenacity. If you buy two of these items, you will not get 70 tenacity. You will only benefit from 35.

- Mercury Treads
- Spirit of the Ancient Golem
- Zephyr

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tenacity)

Comment: Hah, whoops. Totally right, my bad. :)

Comment: So it applies to time, right?

Comment: @Zonengorg Thats right, it only affects the amount of time a CC lasts.

Comment: Might be prudent to mention that Tenacity doesn't stack; only the highest individual tenacity value applies. Merc Treads + Cloak and Dagger nets the same reduction as just Cloak and Dagger.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I´ll edit the question so it is clear that Tenacity is unique and wont stack.

Comment: Does Tenacity works on **SNARE** effect ?

Comment: @MichelAyres, yes a snare is essentially setting the movement speed to 0. So its duration will be shortened by tenacity.

Answer (score 0):

They don't stack, you can only get the effect from one of the tenacity items. Each point of tenacity reduces the CC by 1%, so any of the tenacity items will reduce it by a total of 35%.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not asking about the stack, I am asking about How Tenacity works, just mentioned the items that has the Tenacity passive.

Comment: The second part of my answer explains that, each of the items reduce the duration of the CC by 35%(one for each point of tenacity).

Answer (score 0):

Tenacity is covered fairly well on its [Wikia entry](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tenacity).

However, in general you're correct: It's a percentage reduction of many, but not all, CC effects. The percentage reduction is the same as the value of the stat; i.e., 35 Tenacity means a 35% reduction of CC effects.

It does not work on Displacement Effects (knockups, knockbacks, and pulls) or on suppression. As Jay points out, it also does not impact the *magnitude* of a slow, but only the duration of the slow.

You cannot stack Tenacity items, so at this point, you can only get 35 Tenacity (as all items give the same amount). *However*, Tenacity does stack multiplicatively with other forms of CC reduction. For example, at max level Trundle's Contaminate gives him 40% CC reduction. If you have 35 Tenacity, your final CC reduction is 54% (35% of 40 is 14, 40 + 14 = 54).

Comment: I just noticed you did your math wrong for tenacity. It should be 35 * 1.4 = 49 tenacity. At the end it should be 35 + 14 rather than 40 + 14. Although in season 3 Trundle's contaminate doesn't give him CC reduction anymore, this still applies to Irelia.

Answer (score -1):

35 tenacity = 35 % = stronk. [See here.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tenacity_%28stat%29)

Comment: It would help if you quoted from the wiki next time instead of a generic comment.