# Does tenacity decrease Warwicks ult damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

**Tenacity** reduces the time of crowd control effects(such as a suppress)

So if we take Warwick's ult :

> ACTIVE: Warwick blinks to target enemy champion, suppressing the target for 1.8 seconds and damaging the target 5 times in 1/3-second intervals. Warwick gains 30% life steal for the duration. Each of his strikes triggers on-hit effects and benefits from life steal and full stacks of Eternal Thirst.

And he uses his ult on a champion with 35% tenacity making the suppress last for 1.17. 
This is not enough time to do 5 attack with a 1/3 second interval.

Does this mean that he will only do 3 attacks? or will he still do damage after the target has broken free?

Comment: Definitely check out [our page on Tenacity](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58174/how-does-tenacity-work?rq=1). Although Tenacity doesn't affect Warwick's ult, any duration-based effect that is reduced by tenacity will still produce full results over the duration - see [Nasus' patch notes](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.123) where Riot patched a Wither bug. They've gone through all cases where Tenacity was reducing too many effects and fixed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Tenacity: The duration of stuns, slows, 
taunts, fears, silences, blinds 
and immobilizes are reduced by 35%.
```

Suppress is not affected by tenacity.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mercury%27s_Treads

Comment: So technically tenacity does not reduce all Crowd control?

Comment: @SirDuckduck Exactly! Just the ones mentioned above.

Comment: More accurately, Tenacity affects everything except for Suppression and Airborne (pulls/grabs, knockups, knockbacks). That is, it affects things like Charm and Polymorph, even though it's not in the flavour text. (ping @Sirduckduck)

Answer (score 3):

Tenacity does not reduce Suppression or Airborne, Quicksilver Sash/Mercurial Scimitar actives WILL prevent the rest of the damage, but that's not tenacity.

See this question for more details. [How does Tenacity work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58174/how-does-tenacity-work?rq=1)

Comment: Even if you use QSS or Mercurial Scimitar, Warwick will still attack you until you move out of his attack range.